# Using Rack to run a React application is not working as it should

Tags: ruby, reactjs, svg

My idea is using Rack to load a web application separated in two parts. This is the structure:

```
my_app
     |______api
     |        |______poros
     |
     |______fe
     |       |______build
     |       |______node_modules
     |       |______package.json
     |       |______public
     |       |           |______ index.html
     |       |           ...
     |       |______README.md
     |       |______src
     |                |______index.js
     |                ...
     |______config.ru
```

The **fe** part (which stands for front-end) is a React application created with `create-react-app`. I've built it with

```
npm run build
```

and then its static optimized build is under `my_app/fe/build` directory.

This is my `my_app/config.ru`:

```
#\ -w -p 3000

require 'emeraldfw'

use Rack::Reloader, 0
use Rack::ContentLength

run EmeraldFW::Loader.new
```

And this is my `EmeraldFW::Loader` class, which is part of a gem installed and running fine.

```
module EmeraldFW
  class Loader

    def call(env)
      path_info = (env['PATH_INFO'] == '/') ? '/index.html' : env['PATH_INFO']
      extension = path_info.split('/').last.split('.').last
      file = File.read("fe/build#{path_info}")
      [200,{'Content-Type' => content_type[extension]},[file]]
    end

    def content_type
      {
        'html' => 'text/html',
        'js'   => 'text/javascript',
        'css'  => 'text/css',
        'svg'  => 'image/svg+xm',
        'ico'  => 'image/x-icon',
        'map'  => 'application/octet-stream'
      }
    end

  end
end
```

As you may see, this is all quite simple. I capture the request with in my `EmeraldFW::Loader` class and transform its `path_info` it a bit. If the request is '/' I rewrite it to '/index.html' before doing anything else. In all cases I prepend `fe/build` to make it load from the static build of the React application.

When I run

```
rackup config.ru
```

and load the application at `http://localhost:3000` the result is completely fine:

> [2017-03-15 21:28:23] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
>
> [2017-03-15 21:28:23] INFO  ruby 2.3.3 (2016-11-21) [x86_64-linux]
>
> [2017-03-15 21:28:23] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=11728 port=3000
>
> ::1 - - [15/Mar/2017:21:28:27 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 386 0.0088
>
> ::1 - - [15/Mar/2017:21:28:27 -0300] "GET /static/css/main.9a0fe4f1.css HTTP/1.1" 200 623 0.0105
>
> ::1 - - [15/Mar/2017:21:28:27 -0300] "GET /static/js/main.91328589.js HTTP/1.1" 200 153643 0.0086
>
> ::1 - - [15/Mar/2017:21:28:28 -0300] "GET /static/media/logo.5d5d9eef.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 2671 0.0036
>
> ::1 - - [15/Mar/2017:21:28:28 -0300] "GET /static/js/main.91328589.js.map HTTP/1.1" 200 1705922 0.1079
>
> ::1 - - [15/Mar/2017:21:28:28 -0300] "GET /static/css/main.9a0fe4f1.css.map HTTP/1.1" 200 105 0.0021

As you may see, all resources are loading correctly, with the correct mime types. But it happens that my default React logo, which should be spinning in my app frontpage, is not there! As if it wasn't loaded.

[image]

The big picture of all this is having this rack middleware loading the React front-end of the app and, at the same time, redirecting correctly the api requests made with `fetch` from the front-end to the **poros** (Plain Old Ruby Objects) which are the API part.

The concept is quite simple. But I just can't understand why this specific resource, the svg logo, is not loading.

Comment: If you just need to serve static files... why not use nginx? and if you need a Ruby backend, consider using either the hosting server to serve static files or using an existing [static file server](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) / [middleware](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/Rack/Static) (i.e. `iodine` has a built-in static file server that never even enters the Ruby GIL).... By "rewriting the wheel" you're both waisting time and ignoring a security risk (consider `path_info == '/../src/...` or root access at `//...`).

Comment: P.S. did you try printing out the requested files into a log, just to check that the request for the image file is both arrives at the server and is correctly formed (spelling etc').

Comment: @Myst I thank you for your advice, but my project IS rewriting the wheel. What I am writing is a programming environment which involves the orchestration between fronte end (these static files you mention) and the API backend.  And all this code you are seeing here is just the begining. I'll  add security things and much more at the right time, you may be sure.

Comment: Ed, thanks for clarifying. Just Two last thought....: (1) In this case the environment will include `Rack`, so it could probably still leverage `Rack::Static`, whether directly or through inheritance and modification; and (2) I would also consider that serving static files using Ruby is often (but not always) less performant, due to both [the GIL](https://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/8085491-nobody-understands-the-gil), memory loads (loading the whole file to the memory can often be avoided), `sendfile` availability and cases in which HTTP caching is neglected.

Comment: Oh, these are great suggestions! Thanks a lot. I'll read more about `Rack::Static`. I've considered your point about serving static files with Ruby. I considered the possibility of having two separate processes, one to serve the static files and the other to manage the API (vack-end) requests. Still trying to figure the best way.

Comment: @Myst, you were completely right about `Rack::Static`. Much easier to configure it and surely faster.

Comment: The error was really stupid, @Myst. A mere typo, according to the answer I  posted. But it was worth asking here because of your suggestions.

Comment: I'm happy you both solved the issue and improved your implementation. I would consider testing against a hybrid stack as well (even if only as an optional alternative), where static files are served by the app-server (i.e. `iodine`'s `-www` option) or the proxy (i.e. using `nginx`) rather than the app's middleware. This is especially relevant when you get concurrent requests for the app and for the static files - since the concurrency model might be very different between the middleware and the server layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all a matter of wrong mime type, caused by a typo.

It may be clearly seen in my question that I wrote:

```
def content_type
  {
    'html' => 'text/html',
    'js'   => 'text/javascript',
    'css'  => 'text/css',
    'svg'  => 'image/svg+xm',  # <== Here is the error!!!
    'ico'  => 'image/x-icon',
    'map'  => 'application/octet-stream'
  }
end
```

when the correct mime type for SVG files is `'image/svg-xml'`, with an 'l'...

This was making the browser ignore the file received and so it won't display it correctly.